# I need to use the fancytooldtips package in a number of plain tex documents

Tags: plain-tex, conversion, fancytooltips

I have been handed down a number of rather long documents, compiled in plain Tex. My task is to implement the `fancytooltip` package in these documents for various purposes. The package  in question is only compatible with latex according to it's documentation. 
After doing some research I have come to the conclusion that I am faced with one of two options. Either rewrite(convert) the source files so they compile under `LaTeX` or somehow import needed packages into plain Tex.

What is the better option? The documents I have mentioned don't have any complicated structure, they are for all intents and purposes `math` books. What should I be considering here? Which of the 2 options is going to be faster?

I am a novice at `TeX` but I probably already gave myself away with the question.

Thank you!

Comment: Since you're a novice in `TeX`, both ways are hard, but I assume that converting the `plain TeX` files to `LaTeX` is easier, in this case. The only effort to make the `.sty` conversion to `Plain TeX` worth is a huge bunch of original source codes so the amount of file conversions will outnumber the time you need to transform the `.sty` file

Comment: and see http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-e.html

Comment: I didn't solved features like facytooltips in plain TeX because these features are not supported in all PDF viewers. It is not good idea to create a PDF dependent on used viewer. So, I recommend: don't use features from fancytooltips.

Comment: One can consider a 3rd option : using the package [plain](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/carlisle/)
by David Carlisle.

Comment: @touhami I didn't know about that package, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks for the tip! I will just convert all the files to latex, sounds easier and any future files will also be written in latex.

Comment: Thanks you everybody for your thoughts! Helped me know I am on the right track at least!
Cheers!